# copy elements one by one from one array to another after it passes a condition in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a ruby on rails project. In my controller I have an array and I need to copy all the from this array to another except the ones that does not pass the condition.

For example i have an array

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

i will take an input from the user. if the user's input is 3 then it has to copy all other elements from the array 'A' to array 'B' except 3. The array B has to be this [1,2,4,5]

How do i do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. I see you have been given a couple of answers - hopefully that will help you. However, normally at Stack Overflow we kind of expect you to have a go at it yourself first to see how far you can get on your own. This shows that you are willing to put in some effort yourself before asking for help. It also helps you to learn better because trying to figure it out yourself will be more effective for you than just asking somebody else to give you the answer. Try it next time :)

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby documentation for [Array](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Array.html) provides you most of the information you need to manipulate an Array.

For example, you can use [`Array#reject`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) to remove the values matching a condition or [`Array#delete`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete)

In your case:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
# value taken from the user
input = params[:input].to_i

a.delete(input)
# now a is the array without the element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = a.select { |element| element != 3 }
```

You can use any condition in select.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select